# Handlebars how to reference a {{lookup this ../name}} with an if

Tags: handlebars.js

There are two each loops , the outer loop 'fields' 'name' value is referenced by the inner loop using {{lookup this ../name}} and is rendering correctly.Each {{../message}} can contain an element {{name}}. I wish with the '{{lookup this ../name}}' being null or undefined that renders nothing rather that a blank space. I was hoping there was an easy way to us if to resolve this.I tried to use an {{#if this ../name}} {{/if} around the area but an error generated e.g.

```
{{#each ../message}}
  {{#if this ../name}}
     <a href = "https://issues.jboss.org/browse/{{key}}"> 
     <button class="mini ui blue button"><i class="key icon"></i> {{key}}</button></a>
     <button class="mini ui blue basic button">{{lookup this ../name}}</button><br>
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}

TypeError: Cannot read property 'includeZero' of undefined
```

Here is the code as it stands.

```
  <div class="ui raised segment">
    <div class="ui styled accordion">
        <div class="title">
            <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
            Results
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <p class="transition hidden">
            <div class="ui styled accordion">
                {{#each fields}}
                <div class="title">
                    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                    {{name}}
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <p class="transition hidden">
                            {{#each ../message}}
                              <a href = "https://issues.jboss.org/browse/{{key}}"> <button class="mini ui blue button"><i class="key icon"></i> {{key}} </button></a>
                                    <button class="mini ui blue basic button">{{lookup this ../name}}</button><br>
                            {{/each}}
                    </p>
                </div>
               {{/each}}
            </div>
            </p>
        </div>
```